# What's the advantage of having a type to represent a function?

Tags: f#

What's the advantage of having a type represent a function?

For example, I have observed the following snippet:

```
type Soldier = Soldier of PieceProperties  
type King = King of PieceProperties  
type Crown = Soldier -> King
```

Is it just to support Partial Application when additional args have yet to be satisfied?

Comment: Same reason you give names to everything else - values, functions, modules, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fyodor Soikin says in the comments

> Same reason you give names to everything else - values, functions,
>   modules, etc.

In other words, think about programming in assembly which typically does not use types, (yes I am aware of [typed assembly](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/talc/)) and all of the problems that one can have and then how many of those problems are solved or reduced by adding types.

So before you programmed with a language that supported functions but that used static typing, you typed everything. Now that you are using F# which has static typing and functions, just extend what you have been using typing for but now add the ability to type the functions.

To quote Benjamin C. Pierce from ["Types and Programming Languages"](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/)

> A type system is a tractable syntactic method for proving the absence
>   of certain program behaviors by classifying phrases according to the
>   kinds of values they compute.

As noted in "Types and Programming Languages" Section 1.2

> What Type Systems Are Good For
>
> - Detecting Errors
> - Abstraction
> - Documentation
> - Language Safety
> - Efficiency

TL;DR

One of the places that I find named type function definitions invaluable is when I am building parser combinators. During the construction of the functions I fully type the functions so that I know what the types are as opposed to what type inferencing will infer they are which might be different than what I want. Since the function types typically have several parameters it is easier to just give the function type a name, and then use that name everywhere it is needed. This also saves time because the function definition is consistent and avoid having to debug an improperly declared function definition; yes I have made mistakes by doing each function type by hand and learned my lesson. Once all of the functions work, I then remove the type definitions from the functions, but leave the type definition as comments so that it makes the code easier to understand.

A side benefit of using the named type definitions is that when creating test cases, the typing rules in the named function will ensure that the data used for the test is of the correct type. This also makes understanding the data for the test much easier to understand when you come back to it after many months.

Another advantage is that using function names makes the code easier to understand because when a person new to the code looks at if for the first time they can spot the consistency of the names. Also if the names are meaningful then it makes understanding the code much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that functions are also values in F#. And you can do pretty much the same stuff with them as other types. For example you can have a function that returns other functions. Or you can have a list that stores functions. In these cases it will help if you are explicit about the function signature. The  function type definition will help you to constrain on the parameters and return types. Also, you might have a complicated type signature, a type definition will make it more readable. This maybe a bit contrived but you can do *fun(ky)* stuff like this:

```
type FuncX = int -> int
type FuncZ = float -> float -> float

let addxy (x:int)  :FuncX  = (+) x
let subxy :FuncX = (-) x
let addz (x:float) :FuncZ = 
    fun (x:float) -> (fun y -> x + y)

let listofFunc = [addxy 10;addxy 20; subxy 10]
```

If you check the type of listofFunc you will see it's `FuncX list`. Also the `:FuncX` refers to the return type of the function. But we could you use it as an input type as well:

```
let compFunc (x:FuncX) (z:FuncX)  =
    [(x 10);(z 10)]

compFunc (addxy 10) (addxy 20)
```